# virt-install hangs - GPU Passthrough for Virtual Machines

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, qemu, kvm

I want to run VMs that uses host's GPU. For that, I followed [this docs](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=kvm&f=11) to enable modules/grub configurations. Looks like I successfully configured, I can see `dmesg | grep -i vfio`. But when I run `virt-install`, it is hanging forever, parallely I can't run even `virsh list --all`. Every time I have to restart my laptop, in order to run any `virsh/virt-install` commands again.

```
veeru@ghost:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for veeru: 
root@ghost:/home/veeru# virt-install \
> --name vm0 \
> --ram 12028 \
> --disk path=/home/veeru/ubuntu14-HD.img,size=30 \
> --vcpus 2 \
> --os-type linux \
> --os-variant ubuntu16.04 \
> --network bridge=bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --console pty,target_type=serial \
> --location /home/veeru/Downloads/ubuntu-16.04.5.iso --force \
> --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial' \
> --host-device 01:00.0 \
> --features kvm_hidden=on \
> --machine q35 

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                    |    0 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving file content...                                                                      |    0 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving file info...                                                                         |   67 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                      | 6.8 MB  00:00:00     
Retrieving file initrd.gz...                                                                    |  14 MB  00:00:00
```

Below is the output when I do `strace` of process for above command

```
veeru@ghost:~$ sudo strace -p 9747
strace: Process 9747 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>
```

PS: My laptop is `Predator Helios 300`(UEFI-Secure Boot), GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX1050Ti, Ubuntu Mate 18.04(Installed nvidia drivers), 8GB Ram,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see the problem, the GPU is already being used by host(my laptop) i.e it is busy. So, when I run `virt-install` command, it hangs forever which is no wonder.

In order to resolve the issue, switch your X11 to use CPU. I use Ubuntu Mate 18.06 which has handy tool to switch like in below screenshot

[image]

Ater that logout and login and check nvidia GPU is not being used by any process by running `nvidia-smi`; it should similar output like below.

```
veeru@ghost:~$ nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Now you should able to run `virt-install` like me.